# Google Play Developer API: "startTimeMillis" is updated when it should not

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscriptions

I am developing an application with in-app subscriptions. On our servers, I check the validity of each subscription through the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions).

As stated in the docs, a request to the Purchases.subscriptions endpoint, returns something like that:

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "startTimeMillis": long,
  "expiryTimeMillis": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean
}
```

However, I am finding some strange behavior with it. When a user cancels a subscription through Google Play app, the "startTimeMillis" field **is updated to the time of cancellation**.

According to the documentation, "startTimeMillis" is "Time at which the subscription was granted", so I expected that this value **should not change**. Could anybody explain me why it is updated after a cancellation?

I have another important question that I can not test yet... Could someone, who has spent several months working with subscriptions, tell me if this "startTimeMillis" **is updated too when the subscription is automatically renewed**? I expect too that this should not change but... now, I am not sure about this.

Thank you

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I have just started working on this. So it will be helpful.

Comment: @blindOSX did you find out if it's updates when renewed?

Comment: To answer the renew question, the answer is YES, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802885/using-an-old-token-to-query-purchases-subscriptions-in-the-google-play-developer

Answer (score 4):

Had similar issue and found that:

1. When user cancels the subscription, `startTimeMillis` won't be changed, only autoRenewing changed to false
2. If the user subscribes again after the cancelation, google will send you a new subscription token, but when querying with the previous token, the response would be changed to the same as the new token, i.e. `startTimeMillis` would be changed